# How can I add a signature field in a PDF? (not a digital signature)

Tags: pdf

We have a PDF Form on an Android tablet and we want to be able to choose it and sign it right then and there with a stylus or finger. Not a digital signature but an ordinary signature.

Is this possible?

Will it require a separate app?